# can roles and tasks exist in the same playbook?

Tags: ansible

```
---
# file: main.yml

- hosts: fotk
  remote_user: fakesudo
  tasks:
  - name: create a developer user
    user: name={{ user }}
          password={{ password }}
          shell=/bin/bash
          generate_ssh_key=yes
          state=present
  roles:
  - { role: create_developer_environment, sudo_user: "{{ user }}" }
  - { role: vim, sudo_user: "{{ user }}" }
```

For some reason the create user task is not running.  I have searched every key phrase I can think of on Google to find an answer without success.

The roles are running which is odd.

Is it possible for a playbook to contain both tasks and roles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually this should be possible and I remember I did this a few times during testing. Might be something with your version - or the order does matter, so that the tasks will be executed after the roles.

I would have posted this as a comment, rather than an answer, but I wouldn't be able to give the following example in a comment:

Whatever might be the reason why your task is not executed, you can always separate your playbook into several plays, like so:

```
---
# file: main.yml

- hosts: fotk
  remote_user: fakesudo
  tasks:
  - name: create a developer user
    user: name={{ user }}
          password={{ password }}
          shell=/bin/bash
          generate_ssh_key=yes
          state=present

- hosts: fotk
  remote_user: fakesudo
  roles:
  - { role: create_developer_environment, sudo_user: "{{ user }}" }
  - { role: vim, sudo_user: "{{ user }}" }
```

Comment: Would I be right in thinking if your playbook looked like this, then its possible both plays might be executed in parallel?

Comment: No, the 2nd play will only start once the first completed.

Comment: if one or more tasks in the first play fail for a specific host, will that host be skipped in the second play that depends on the first play succeeding? eg the first play is "install operating system" and the second play is "install role specific software"  .

Answer (score 36):

You can also do pre_tasks:  and post_tasks: if you need to do things before or after.  From the Docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html

```
- hosts: localhost

  pre_tasks:
    - shell: echo 'hello in pre'

  roles:
    - { role: some_role }

  tasks:
    - shell: echo 'in tasks'

  post_tasks:
    - shell: echo 'goodbye in post'
```

> Gives the output: PLAY [localhost]
>
> ---
>
> GATHERING FACTS
> ***************************************************************  ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK: [shell echo 'hello in pre']
> *********************************************  changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK: [some_role | shell echo 'hello from the role']
> **************************  changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK: [shell echo 'in tasks']
> *************************************************  changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK: [shell echo 'goodbye in post']
> ******************************************  changed: [localhost]
>
> PLAY RECAP
> ********************************************************************  localhost                  : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0
> failed=0

This is with ansible 1.9.1

Comment: I saw that in the docs but for whatever reason, my task won't run.

Comment: Try the simple playbook I posted.  Add a role that just does a shell: echo something and see if that works.  Maybe you have something else going on in your playbook that keeps it from working as you expect.

Answer (score 12):

Short follow up to the already mentioned options by quoting the latest Ansible docs [docs.ansible.com/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html):

> As of Ansible 2.4, you can now use roles inline with any other tasks using import_role or include_role:

```
---    
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - debug:
      msg: "before we run our role"
    - import_role:
      name: example
    - include_role:
      name: example
    - debug:
      msg: "after we ran our role"`
```

Code snippet is also from Ansible docs.

Be aware of the difference between static (import*) & dynamic (include*) usage.

Comment: would this working inside of a role? many of my roles require logging into a cmdb to get information about the system / environment. I created a role called "login" and probably have 5 -6 roles that needs to execute before doing anything else as task logic depends on info from the cmdb.

Answer (score 10):

https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#roles

> If the play still has a ‘tasks’ section, those tasks are executed
>   after roles are applied.

If you wish to run tasks before or after roles are executed, you need to list these under `pre_tasks` and `post_tasks`. Thus, there is no way to run "loose" tasks between two roles. You might want to create a dedicated role for these tasks.

Comment: Please see the answer of @michael-aicher for an update on this. Ansible 2.3 introduced the `include_role` option.