# Ansible: How to implement conditionals for roles? (Getting errors)

Tags: ansible

I have my play as follows:

```
---
- hosts: influxdbmeta_lab, influxdbdata_lab
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
    - shell: "docker ps --format '{{.Image}}' | grep influx"
      register: command_result
    - name: setting fact 
      set_fact: string_to_echo = "{{ command_result.stdout }}"
  roles:
    - role: influxdb-upgrade
      when: (string_to_echo == "--meta")
```

When I run this playbook, I get the following error:

```
TASK [influxdb-upgrade : Creating directories] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [influxmetalab-1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(string_to_echo == \"--meta\")' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((string_to_echo == \"--meta\")): 'string_to_echo' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/zafaab1/git-repos/deploy-vcp-performance/ansible_home/roles/influxdb-upgrade/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# Ensures that the directories are there. For upgrade, Ansible will simply mark this as OK\n- name: Creating directories\n  ^ here\n"}
```

I am just not sure why the string_to_echo is showing up as undefined. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

I have tried various combinations. I tried placing the shell command in the actual tasks for the role: influxdb-upgrade. However, that produces the same error.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280196/ansible-set-fact-not-accessible

Comment: @Chin Huang: It's not, I think. The problem here is the workflow. The link to "ansible set_fact not accessible" shows the wrong syntax.

Comment: @Abdul: The problem would have been immediately obvious if you had posted the complete output.

Answer (score 1):

In a play, **roles are executed before tasks**. When the *roles:* statement was executed the variable *string_to_echo* had not been declared yet.

For example, let's use a simple role with only one task

```
$ cat roles/role1/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: test_var
```

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        test_var: test
    - debug:
        var: test_var
  roles:
    - role1
```

gives

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************

TASK [role1 : debug] ************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test_var": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "test_var": "test"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role) to change the workflow to your needs.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        test_var: test
    - debug:
        var: test_var
    - include_role:
        name: role1
      when: test_var == 'test'
```

Comment: Thank you !! This works !!!      Also similar explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987865/can-roles-and-tasks-exist-in-the-same-playbook